# Advice on translating a 3V3 PWM signal to a 6V PWM signal

Tags: stm32, pwm, servo, level-translation

I'm trying to control 3 20Kg servo motors powered by 6V ([Link to servo motor datasheet here](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81Lbgu+nG6L.pdf)), using an STM32L5 microcontroller. Currently, the design uses an Arduino Pro Mini powered by 5V, and using the Arduino servo.h library to control the servo motors. The design does work, but the servo motor movements are jittery and shaky.

At the moment, I'm considering using something like this: [image: PWM translating circuit. Not final]

That said, I wanted to get a second opinion and/or alternate recommendations for translating the PWM signal. I have been considering optocouplers, but I haven't been able to find one that works within the voltages I'm using (3V3 in and 6V out, though the servos can go up to 6V8). It's a similar story for PWM drivers so far. I also don't want to go overkill with a solution if something like this is best for safety, stability and simplicity.

*edits: I forgot to mention that the current version of what I'm working on uses an Arduino Pro Mini, and that I'm moving it over to STM. Included are details on its current behaviour*

Comment: 6V is the power supply. The servos accept a 3.3V to 5V control signal, so why would you want to make it outside  of the allowable range when you can just connect it directly?

Comment: Just to clarify, you're saying that even if the servo is powered by 6V, it's still meant to take a 5V PWM signal?

Comment: @E.HP.S - I agree with Sphero - the timing diagrams at the end of the datasheet specify the voltage as 3-3 to 5V.

Comment: Oh yeah, you're right. I think I remember seeing that before, but I thought it was odd. I'll test it out and see if anything comes up

Comment: @E.HP.S Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add some information before about the design. It seems to lend credence to your comments. I amended my question with the new information

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I haven't had a chance to test this yet, but would it still be a good idea to use this transistor setup if I was using a 5V PWM signal? I've gone with a simple pull-up resistor on a 5V tolerant PWM pin before, but that was for a smaller servo.

Comment: I don't think you need the transistor at all. Remember - we don't know the input impedance of the RC servo input, so a high value pullup may be worse than a straight connection.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany You were right. It does need a to be pulled up to 5V to get the servo to move weight up and down, but 3V3 can move things left and right. For the record, I am talking about the PWM signal.

Answer (score 1):

This solution is possibly the simplest you can get.

One-transistor level translators are quite popular for 3.3V-5V translation for UART which can go as high as 100+ kHz. So there's nothing wrong with using it. And, personally, I don't see a major concern. Just to prevent false triggers in case the STM32's PWM output is floating, put a resistor from that pin to 3.3V (something like 10k should do).

One thing to consider is the input impedance of the motor's PWM input as it'll interact with, possibly high, output impedance (R2) of the translator i.e. they form a voltage divider. Although the datasheet doesn't state anything regarding that value, I'm assuming it to be not less than a few tens of kiloohms. So, as long as you keep R2 within a few kiloohms you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You'd better use a (MOS)FET (to get the full 0-6V signal swing) and connect your microcontroller output to the gate, and ground the source. Then invert your signal in hardware or software (your choice).

E.g. see [here](https://www.openimpulse.com/blog/2012/06/unidirectional-voltage-level-translators/).